# Base table or view not found: 1146 - While importing products from one DB to another DB

Tags: magento-1.9, database, import, csv

I have a site in magento 1.9.2, I installed a new magento 1.9.2 on my localhost which is blank. I export all products by going into system->dataflow->exports and download file as a csv. Now I am uploading csv file by going through same procedure system->dataflow->imports. I am getting errors

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento1.premier_prod_priceupdate' doesn't exist, query was: insert into premier_prod_priceupdate (sku,newprice, oldprice, datetime) values('010423','7.38','',Now()) 

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type" 

 Image does not exist.
```

I have no table 'premier_prod_priceupdate' in both of my exporting and importing DB. What is the issue ? If Anyone has any idea kindly do let me know how I can fix this.

Comment: thats wierd. DO one thing. Clear all log tables, dataflowexport/import tables. Clear cache and reindex and try again.